# receiving data on laptop but not in android wifi

Tags: android, web-services, nginx, wifi, okhttp

Trying to call a `GET` method in android with OKHTTP & Retrofit, everything is OK with Mobile Data but when using Wifi it acts differently.

some times connection resets by pear and some times `HTTP 504 Unsatisfiable Request (only-if-cached)`
but its ok on post methodes!

the problem is when i use `PostMan`,`chrome`,`wget` etc in my laptop on the same connection it works fine.

i have tested this issue on 5 more devices and the problem was there.

I'm looking for a way to debug it? any suggestion 
on server configuration (nginx) or android?

Comment: What happens if you explicitly disable the HTTP proxy with `proxy(Proxy.NO_PROXY)` on the OkHttpClient? It's possible your WiFi is configured with a proxy that doesn’t actually work.

Comment: fixed by using https!